# While executing test scripts with protractor, mat-select is not showing mat-option on click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

We have a "mat-select" element with name = "model.selectedSubscription" which is a dropdown element.

While executing manually, we are clicking on mat-select to open the "mat-option" list to select from.

However, when we are executing through automation, mat-option is not opening.

I have tried using the protractor click, JSExecutor click as well as Actions class click, but none of them invoked the mat-option list.

I tried waiting for the angular to load, but none worked. Please help me on how I can fix the issue or invoke the mat-option elements to bring them to view.

I even tried to use sendkeys to the mat-select element, but it didn't work.

Please help!!!

Comment: Is your protractor test also clicking on the `mat-select` element first? After clicking that, you might also have to wait for the `mat-option` to display. Anyway, if you need further help, please update your post to include the html and code you've tried.

Comment: I do not have the code with me today... or the application access, but I have clicked on mat-select and waited for mat-option to load for 15 seconds. Manually, the options come in 2 seconds. I will post the code as soon as I have access again

Comment: Are you sure your locator is working correctly? are you setting `waitForAngularEnabled(false)` at any stage?

Comment: yes, infact the other mat-select elements are working fine. Only one is not working.

Comment: out of interest how are you sure your locator is working correctly? Does a isDisplayed return true?

Comment: It is working sir. I am not a novice. Can you ask a better question? Infact, the object is getting clicked as it is highlighted but not generating the mat-option list. In fact, in the automation session, I did a browser.sleep and tried to click manually, but it is not working.

Comment: ok I didn't mean to imply otherwise it's just that many questions that are posted here are actually due to incorrect use of locators. It is interesting that you say the click is not working even when you had the sleep and tried clicking manually. I would advise testing this again by manually launching a new selenium session (access http://localhost:4444/wd/hub if your selenium server is running on default port) and trying your test completely manually. If there is an issue still then this may be a browser driver problem